# Is Windows build-in minimum drag distance parameter DPI-scaled?

Tags: c#, windows, scaling, dpi

I have a window in my application that should only get dragged when the mouse has moved a certain distance. I want this distance to be the same as Windows default, but it seems to be 4 regardless of the DPI scaling of my monitor. 
Do I have to scale the value 4, or is it in fact DPI-aware?

I'm doing the following to check whether I should start dragging or not:

```
    private static bool HasMouseMovedFarEnough(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Assert(_startPoint != null);

        Vector delta = _startPoint.Value - e.GetPosition(null);

        return Math.Abs(delta.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||
               Math.Abs(delta.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance;
    }
```

Comment: It's in pixels. That's the only unscaled, and physicly naturally existing scale.
Maybe the rest of your system is scaled. As soon as you handle DPI you start scaling. The size of a Pixel is variable.

Comment: Okay. But surely if I have set my monitor scaling to 200%, this parameter should then be 8 and not 4, assuming I want the scaling applied in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you buy a 1080x1920 monitor in the shop, it will always tell you this size, and there might be functions that report scaled sized to you, but the size in Pixel will always be unscaled. That's the definition of a Pixel.

If you look in the SourceCode

```
 _minimumHorizontalDragDistance = 
  SystemParameters.ConvertPixel(UnsafeNativeMethods.GetSystemMetrics(SM.CXDRAG))
```

And if you look in the Win32-API

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmetrics

> The number of pixels on either side of a mouse-down point that the
>   mouse pointer can move before a drag operation begins. This allows the
>   user to click and release the mouse button easily without
>   unintentionally starting a drag operation. If this value is negative,
>   it is subtracted from the left of the mouse-down point and added to
>   the right of it.

It says clearly, it's in Pixels.
So as higher the resolution, as finer a user can adjust things.
If you would scale it, the user would have no use of a higher resolution.

Comment: But if a user has scaled their screen to 200%, the resolution is the same and the definition of a pixel is the same, but my window takes up twice as many pixels as before, so I want the user to have to move the mouse twice the distance before dragging is initiated.
This does answer my question; I need to scale the value.

Comment: I just checked: when scaled to 100% the parameter value is 4.0, and when scaled to  250% the value is then 1.6 (4/2.5). If I want the value to be 4 at all times I need to multiply the system parameter value with the scaling factor

Comment: You are confusing a little between "it seems to be 4 all the time" and "I want to be it 4 at all time". One must be wrong.
Actually the user controls the sensibility of it's mouse by controlling the Mouse-Speed. You will get the MouseMove event in any case. What you are checking here is when the system gives you a DragStart Event. You have no control over that, there is no "SetSystemMetrics". If you want to start your dragging earlier, use MouseMove, if you want to start it later, ignore DragStart.